# Passing SecureStrings in Powershell for LDAP query when not a member of domain

Tags: ldap, powershell-2.0, securestring

I've saved a SecureString with ConvertFrom-SecureString to a file and have code to extract and convert the encrypted string back to a SecureString. However, when using the SecureString to authenticate and query a domain with DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher the query fails with a logon error.

I know the encrypted string is saved and retrieved correctly because I can convert the SecureString to plan text and used it to successfully query. What am I doing wrong, is there a better way to accomplish this query? Thanks in advance!

```
#Create file with encrypted string (outside of main script)   
$key = (3,4,2,3,56,34,254,222,1,1,2,23,42,54,33,233,1,34,2,7,6,5,35,43)
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring -key $key | out-file C:\temp\cred.txt

$computer = $env:computername
#Get encrypted string and convert to secure string
$password = get-content C:\Temp\cred1.txt | convertto-securestring -Key $key
$domain = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://you.domain.here","domain\username", $PASSWORD)
    $search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($domain)
    $search.filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$computer))"
    $script:search.findall() | %{$_.GetDirectoryEntry() }
Write-Host $searchresult.distinguishedName
```

If I convert the encrypted string to plain text then I’m able to successfully query the domain I’m not a member of.

```
$computer = $env:computername
#Get encrypted string and convert to secure string
$password = get-content C:\Temp\cred1.txt | convertto-securestring -Key $key

#Convert to plain text string
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)

$domain = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://you.domain.here","domain\username", $PlainPASSWORD)
    $search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($domain)
    $search.filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$computer))"
    $script:search.findall() | %{$_.GetDirectoryEntry() }
```

Comment: I don't see on my box any constructor for DirectoryEntry that accepts SecureString. Where did you find information that this is possible...?

Comment: Like I said maybe I'm doing it wrong. I was going of the AuthenticationType where the default is Secure. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx). I'm knewbie and still trying to understand PowerShell and .Net.